# Mobile Chat Application

Tags: java, codenameone

what technology should I use for mobile chat application so that messaging and media should reach with maximum success rate and should also be saved on server side?

Comment: Googling this question would yield countless of results. Google is your friend!

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think best and easy way to develop chat application you can use front-end for Angular 4 and Cloud fire store or firebase real-time database for back-end data managing. For using this technologies, You can developed high scale chat app quickly.